# SSIS Package "Populate fact_PageRequest" failed. Stuck troubleshooting issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

Where I work, we are using SSIS to generate several reports. They've been running fine for over a year, possibly much longer, but the people to setup and configured the system are no longer here and I am a web developer, I have no experience with SSIS yet, just standard SQL.

Since the middle of July some of the data is no longer being added to the report. I investigated the server it runs on and found that the following error in the Event Viewer started occurring once a day since the day the data no longer appears in the reports.

> Package "Populate fact_PageRequest" failed.

However I can't find any further information about what could be causing the problem.

I opened the `.dtsx` files in the repository for the reports and found "fact_PageRequest" referenced in one of the flowchart sections of the file, but these reports haven't changed since they were made so I'm guessing it's something more configuration or environment related.

Any suggestions or advice on where to look for more information about the error or possible causes would be really appreciated.

The server it's running on is Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to troubleshoot packages. The easiest way assumes that you are using project deployment mode and did not explicitly switch off default logging. Here are the steps:

1. Connect to your database engine with SSMS
2. Expand "Integration Services Catalogs" node
3. Expand SSISDB and locate your package
4. Right click the package -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> All executions

If the package is not there, it is either stored in the msdb database or in the filesystem and other logging way will have to be applied.

Comment: Thanks, the package is in a folder called MSDB so I'm guessing that's where it's being stored.

After some more digging I was able to find a log file. Looks like the relevant error is:

`SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".`

Comment: So is it a folder inside Integration Services Catalogs? If it is, you should be able to access the reports I mentioned. If you find no info there, debug it in SSDT - you need to [extract](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/editing-published-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012.html) the package first. To find packages stored in MSDB you would have to query msdb.dbo.sysssispackages, is this how you found the package?